# C# Winforms Designer: How to copy and paste collections at design-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Suppose I have created the following custom control:

```
public class BookshelfControl : Control
{
    [Editor(typeof(ArrayEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

where `Book` is a simple custom class defined as:

```
public class Book : Component
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Using this, I can easily edit the `Books` collection within the Visual Studio designer.

However, if I create one instance of `BookshelfControl`, then **copy and paste** within the designer, the `Books` collection is not copied, but instead the second control references all the items within the first contol's collection (*e.g.*, `bookshelfControl1.Book[0]` equals `bookshelfControl2.Book[0]`).

Therefore, my question is, **How do I tell the Visual Studio designer to *copy* my `Books` collection when copying and pasting control instances at design time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of research, I believe I have found what needs to be done in order to instruct the designer to copy collection items with a *copy and paste* operation at design time.

Using a custom designer class for my `BookshelfControl`, I can override the `ComponentDesigner.Associated` components property.  According to [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.associatedcomponents(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `ComponentDesigner.AssociatedComponents` property indicates any components to copy or move along with the component managed by the designer during a copy, drag, or move operation.

The modified class ends up being:

```
[Designer(typeof(BookshelfControl.Designer))]
public class BookshelfControl : Control
{
    internal class Designer : ControlDesigner
    {
        private IComponent component;

        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            this.component = component;
        }

        //
        // Critical step getting the designer to 'cache' related object
        // instances to be copied with this BookshelfControl instance:
        //
        public override System.Collections.ICollection AssociatedComponents
        {
            get
            {
                return ((BookshelfControl)this.component).Books;
            }
        }
    }

    [Editor(typeof(ArrayEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The result from the `AssociatedComponents` property provides the designer with a collection of objects (which can be nested controls, other objects, primitives, *etc.*) that get copied to the clipboard to be pasted elsewhere.

In testing, I have determined that the `AssociatedComponents` property is read immediately after the copy command (*i.e.*, `CTRL + C`) is issued at design-time.

I hope this helps others wanting to save time tracking down this rather obscure feature!

Answer (score 1):

My answer fix your problem unless you have so many things around.
You should NOT inherit `Book` from `Component`.
Simply use :

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Book 
    {

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public string Genre { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

I tested it and it worked correctly.
If you really want to use `Component` instead you should create a custom [EditorAttribute class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) .

Comment: Thanks, this would probably work if I was able to avoid inheriting from `Component`, but unfortunately `Book` has additional design-time properties and methods which require it.  +1 for a simple, workable solution, however.  Please see below for actual solution used.